# En angular Progress bar entre componentes que tenga longitud variable no se ve

Tags: html, angular, web, angular-material, scss

estoy haciendo una barra de progreso con multiples fases, entre cada fase representada con un check, se tiene una progress bar que, en caso de por ejemplo 2 fases seria una sola barra entre los dos check que ocupa todo el ancho de donde este contenido, en caso de ser 3 fases tendria que tener otro check en el medio y dos progress bar uniendose con con las otras fases y asi si sigo agregando, el problema es que se generan los check pero las progress bar no se ven:

```
<div class="phase-progress">
    <div class="phase-container" *ngFor="let phase of phases; let i = index">
        <div class="phase-item">
            <app-check></app-check>
        </div>
        <mat-progress-bar class="progress-bar" mode="determinate" value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <button (click)="addPhase()">Agregar Fase</button> 

.phase-progress {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%; 
    justify-content: space-between; 
  }
  
  .phase-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .phase-item {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  
  .progress-bar {
    flex-grow: 1; 
    width:auto;

  }
```

[image: asi se ve con esto cuando agrego varias fases, pero no se ve la barra que las un]

Asi se ve con esto cuando agrego varias fases, pero no se ve la barra que las une.
si el width de la progress bar en el scss lo pongo con un valor fijo si aparecen, pero la idea es que sea auto para que se mas larga o corta dependiendo la cantidad de espacio que tiene por las fases que hay.